# What is the Difference between Subscriber, Listener and Consumer in Messaging Queues?

Tags: activemq-classic, publish-subscribe

In publish/subscribe model and Point to Point model, we hear the words Subscriber/Listener and Consumer. How does this work?

Specifically where the messages first flows and how the flow works between these 3.

Comment: i invite to read some EIP like http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/DurableSubscription.html and http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/EventDrivenConsumer.html

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is:

**Publisher/Sender:**

The service that publishes events or send commands to other services.

In publishing you do not specify a specific address, meaning that all the services subscribing to the type of message published can consume it, while in sending commands you specify address of services you want them specifically to receive the command sent.

**Subscriber/Listener:**

The service that subscribe to a certain published message type, or listens to a sent command, Consumer is normally a technical term that represent the class consuming the message inside Subscriber/Listener.

Meaning that each Subscriber/Listener has consumer inside that receive the message, and process it.

Comment: This answer is not related at all to the question.